# Query Run Fast but Slow In Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I have this query in MySQL

```
SELECT sr.rule_id, 
sr.rule_type, 
srv.voucher_code,
sr.name, 
sr.description, 
sr.from_date, 
sr.to_date, 
sr.tnc,
CASE 
WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%items.RowTotal%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(sr.conditions, LOCATE('"attribute":"items.RowTotal","operator":">=","value":"',sr.conditions) + CHAR_LENGTH('"attribute":"items.RowTotal","operator":">=","value":"')),'"',1) AS UNSIGNED) 
WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%items.SubTotal%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(sr.conditions, LOCATE('"attribute":"items.SubTotal","operator":">=","value":"',sr.conditions) + CHAR_LENGTH('"attribute":"items.SubTotal","operator":">=","value":"')),'"',1) AS UNSIGNED)
ELSE NULL END 'Minimum Transaction',
srv.max_redemption,
sr.discount_type,
sr.discount_amount,
CASE WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value":"A"}%' OR sr.conditions NOT LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value"%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END BU_AHI,
CASE WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value":"H"}%' OR sr.conditions NOT LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value"%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END BU_HCI,
CASE WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value":"T"}%' OR sr.conditions NOT LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value"%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END BU_TGI,
sr.conditions
FROM ruparupadb_2.salesrule sr 
LEFT JOIN ruparupadb_2.salesrule_voucher srv ON sr.rule_id = srv.rule_id 
WHERE rule_type ='voucher' AND (sr.from_date <= endDate AND startDate <= sr.to_date);
```

When i try to run this query it has a good performance and finish under 1s.
But when i tried to make it as Stored Procedure and tried to call it

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `ruparupadb_report`.`InternalAudit_DataRuleVoucher`(in startDate varchar(50), endDate varchar(50))
BEGIN
SELECT sr.rule_id, 
sr.rule_type, 
srv.voucher_code,
sr.name, 
sr.description, 
sr.from_date, 
sr.to_date, 
sr.tnc,
CASE 
WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%items.RowTotal%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(sr.conditions, LOCATE('"attribute":"items.RowTotal","operator":">=","value":"',sr.conditions) + CHAR_LENGTH('"attribute":"items.RowTotal","operator":">=","value":"')),'"',1) AS UNSIGNED) 
WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%items.SubTotal%' THEN CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(sr.conditions, LOCATE('"attribute":"items.SubTotal","operator":">=","value":"',sr.conditions) + CHAR_LENGTH('"attribute":"items.SubTotal","operator":">=","value":"')),'"',1) AS UNSIGNED)
ELSE NULL END 'Minimum Transaction',
srv.max_redemption,
sr.discount_type,
sr.discount_amount,
CASE WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value":"A"}%' OR sr.conditions NOT LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value"%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END BU_AHI,
CASE WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value":"H"}%' OR sr.conditions NOT LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value"%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END BU_HCI,
CASE WHEN sr.conditions LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value":"T"}%' OR sr.conditions NOT LIKE '%{"attribute":"items.shipping.StoreCode","operator":"%","value"%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END BU_TGI,
sr.conditions
FROM ruparupadb_2.salesrule sr 
LEFT JOIN ruparupadb_2.salesrule_voucher srv ON sr.rule_id = srv.rule_id 
WHERE rule_type ='voucher' AND (sr.from_date <= endDate AND startDate <= sr.to_date);
END
```

it takes so long to finish using this call function

```
CALL ruparupadb_report.InternalAudit_DataRuleVoucher(startDate,endDate)
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: run `EXPLAIN SELECT...` outside and inside the procedure and compare the outputs.

Comment: `AND (sr.from_date <= endDate AND startDate <= sr.to_date)` What is `endDate` and `startDate` in single query?

Comment: Start by using the `DATE` datatype wherever appropriate _instead of_ `VARCHAR`.